# SharePoint 2013 using deleted app domain

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, domain, web-application-zones

I followed this tutorial [Configure an Environment for Apps for SharePoint 2013](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2013/02/13/configure-an-environment-for-apps-for-sharepoint-2013-aspx/)
to create an app domain called **mytestapps.com** but later decided that's not a good name and I deleted the domain Zone and created another one called **mjrapp.com**.

My problem is that when I install apps, they are still using the deleted domain(mytestapps.com) instead of new one(mjrapp.com).

I have tried to change the App URLs in the central administration to be **mjrapp.com** but not working. I have also tried reinstalling the app service, subscription service and metadata service but still not getting what I want.

Any assistance will be appreciated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the answer guys use  **Remove-SPWebApplicationAppDomain**

Comment: What steps did you follow to re-configure app domain without impacting existing SharePoint hosted and Provider hosted add-ins?